# Kendo grid save and load grid options with column filtrable transport not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I save and then trying load grid options from localStorage without column `filtrable dataSource:transport.read`, everithing is ok. But if save and then trying load with filtrable `dataSource:transport` I have a script error!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jvp-B5UG_xNE03YUw2eWhEUE0/view?usp=sharing

Small example of what I mean:

1.

```
{ field: "status_name",
    title: "Status",
    headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate("Status"),
    width:"90px",
    filterable: {

        multi: true,
        search: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        checkAll: false,
        dataSource: [

            { status_name: "wait"},
            { status_name: "decline"},
            { status_name: "approve"}

       ]
   }
}
```

2.

```
{ field: "status_name",
    title: "Status",
    headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate("Status"),
    width:"90px",
    filterable: {

        multi: true,
        search: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        checkAll: false,
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "some_url",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
       })
   }
}
```

In both cases data in `dataSource()` is same! But in second case a have this problem.
My code for save and load state:

```
$("#save-columns-state-button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
});

$("#load-columns-state-button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
        if (options) {
            grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options));
        }
    });
```

Reading and writing from/in localStorage are successfully!
Problem in this place `grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options))`.
How to resolve this problem? How I can save state and then load without errors?

Answer (score 0):

If everything good in first case maybe, try to save options without field 'transport' !?

Comment: in my case dataSource must dynamic load, becouse data in dataSource always changing